# Making div visible/hidden based on another div angular form option selection

Tags: angular, typescript

Having an issue with setting div visible/hidden.
     On selection change of an option in a nested div, make the current  hidden and other  visible.
    I am having an issue with this.  Whatever changes you do it's not hiding the other div.
    The following is the plunker:
        https://plnkr.co/edit/bhjWdCtnStGtr3G74ngN?p=preview

```
In the above Plunker, if I select an option, then it should hide the Production Type drop-down and show only Credit Card and Bank Account.


Thanks
Karthey
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You were missing `this.isOtherPay=true;` inside of your `change` function, where keyword `this` relates to the current context, which is the class itself

**EDIT:** Here is a complete [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/p97ufEP82CfZtfdS0CDq?p=preview) code